# Google calander did not identify the email markups

Tags: html, email, google-calendar-api, html-email, email-templates

I want to send mail to my Gmail account about an event and it should be added automatically to my calendar ( As in redbus ticket booking). I use email markups for this. But it doesn't work. Google didn't identify the mail.
I use the following markup as email template.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":              "http://schema.org",
      "@type":                 "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
      "underName": {
        "@type":               "Person",
        "name":                "John Smith"
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type":               "Event",
        "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
        "startDate":           "2018-11-20T08:30:00-08:00",
        "location": {
          "@type":             "Place",
          "name":              "Moscone Center",
          "address": {
            "@type":           "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion":   "CA",
            "postalCode":      "94103",
            "addressCountry":  "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

what is wrong with this

Comment: Email clients do not let you embed javascript into the email.

Comment: Then how google identifies hotel bookings and bus and flight ticket booking

Comment: Through the URL string.

Comment: @scoopzilla which URL?